# PHP OOP array duplicated in method

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Very new to OOP so please bear with me. I have a method that checks characteristics of a persons array and has a counter to keep track of things. The persons array starts off as serialized data, which I'm converting to an array with the unzerialize() function. When I do `var_dump($this->people)` in the constructor, I get the correct values. When I do the same in any of the other methods in the class, the array is duplicated a number of times and my counter produces incorrect values.

Also doing `echo gettype($this->people)` in the constructor results in `array` as expected, but in the other methods results in `arrayarrayarrayarray....`

What could be causing this duplication? And how do I solve it?

*** EDIT ***

Sorry for the confusion. I did not know where the problem was so it was difficult for me to explain properly.

The problem is not with my class definition, but how I am using the object. I have reworked the code to illustrate. I thought that once the object was instantiated, the values produced by it would be set, however it turns out that each time I call the `get_results()` method, `$this->num` is incremented and the value is persisted.

So my question is, how do I run the `get_results()` method once, and access the  `results[]` array without changing the values? I was hoping I could do something like `if($nums['results']['num'] == 1)` but that results in a fatal error.

```
class DoStuff
{
    private $num;
    public $results;

    public function __construct($val)
    {
        $this->num = $val;
        $this->results = [];
    }

    private function compute_num()
    {
        $this->num++;
        $this->results['num'] = $this->num;
        return $this->results;
    }

    public function get_results()
    {
        $this->results = $this->compute_num();
        return $this->results;
    }   
}

$nums = new DoStuff(0);
$nums->get_results();

if($nums->get_results()['num'] == 1)
{
    printf('<p>(if) Num is: %d</p>', $nums->get_results()['num']);
}
else 
{
    printf('<p>(else) Num is: %d</p>', $nums->get_results()['num']);
}

// Prints (else) Num is: 3
```

Comment: what is your problem actually? confusing.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show in which all functions did you write `var_dump`? Looking at the array it seems `var_dump` is written twice in the code.

Comment: Your code working fine at my end. Please check or edit your question and put code correctly.

Comment: *but in the other methods...* - what other methods? Your PHP snippet does not contain anything other than `get_health()`, and it echoes 1 as it should.

Comment: It may possible you are trying to var_dump the array at constructor and in get_health method at same time which causes it to print twice.

Comment: For removing your confusion, please check this:-https://eval.in/519247  .  It shows your code works fine.

Comment: For brevity I have not included all the other methods contained in this class. The get_health method is where my counter is. Placing var_dump($this->people) in any other method than the constructor results in the array being duplicated up to 12 times. Inside the constructor it is correct. Outside of it is incorrect. It is not being looped over, and it is not because I'm doing multiple var_dumps.

Comment: Please show us the code that works incorrectly. It's very hard to understand the issue when you show us the code that works perfectly fine.

Comment: So your question seems pretty unclear what you want to achieve over here. Please redefine your question with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was trying to access an object as an array. The solution is to use `get_object_vars()` after running the `get_results()` method.

```
$nums = new DoStuff(0);
$nums->get_results();
$nums = get_object_vars($nums);

if($nums['results']['num'] == 1)
{
    printf('<p>(if) Num is: %d</p>', (int) $nums['results']['num']);
}
else 
{
    printf('<p>(else) Num is: %d</p>', (int) $nums['results']['num']);
}

// Prints: (if) Num is: 1
```

Comment: if your problem is solved it is a good practice to accept your own answer. It will make your question as answered in the system as well.